# Powershell Script run from ISE console seems not to end

Tags: powershell, debugging

I'm new to Powershell and ISE, so am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

When I execute the following script from within Powershell ISE, it runs, and I get correct output, but the debugger is left running. Status shows:
"Running script / selection. Press Ctrl+Break to stop. Press Ctrl+B to break into debugger."

Ctrl+B seemingly does nothing.
After hitting Ctrl+Break, status shows "Stopping". At that point, all debug options are greyed-out. I can edit and save the script, but am unable to run it (or any other script) again. All I can do at that point is close and restart Powershell ISE.

Thank you.

```
netsh wlan show profiles
#
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
$ProfileName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter Profile name', 'Thing to find', 'WiMyFi')
#
 If ($ProfileName) {
  $Output = netsh.exe wlan show profiles name= $ProfileName key=clear
  #
  Echo $Output
  #
  $SSID = $Output | Select-String -Pattern 'SSID Name'
  $SSID = ($SSID -split ":")[-1].Trim() -replace '"'
  #
  $PW = $Output | Select-String -Pattern 'Key Content'
  $PW = ($PW -split ":")[-1].Trim() -replace '"'

  Write-host 'SSID:' $SSID ', Password:' $PW
  }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you use ISE instead of a more mature editor like Visual Studio Code? It's known that ISE can behave differently then expected.

Comment: do you see the same problem in the powershell.exe console?

Comment: I noticed the script is, in fact, not running on ISE. It's getting hung on:
 $ProfileName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter Profile name', 'Thing to find', 'WiMyFi'). Is there a Module that needs to be loaded? It runs fine from powershell.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Using VisualBasic, you need to use double-quotes `"` instead of single-quotes `'` on strings.

Try

```
$ProfileName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Profile name", "Thing to find", "WiMyFi")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Theo, but that didn't seem to make a difference. The script is still failing at $ProfileName = ....

Comment: @ModelsRUs Are you sure? For me (PowerShell 5.1) it hangs with the single quotes. When I use all double quotes there's no problem..

Comment: Hopefully I'm narrowing in on the issue. The $ProfileName = statement seems to work when I step through the code, but fails when I attempt to just run it (F5) as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

see: [Powershell Script works in Debugger but not at normal run(ISE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921995/powershell-script-works-in-debugger-but-not-at-normal-runise/43922530)

If I add:  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

after:  Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic

and before:  $ProfileName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter Profile name', 'Thing to find', 'WiMyFi')

then the script runs. Go figure!

Comment: I think you should award @VictorWolf for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566373/9898643) at least with an upvote.